# Adjusting the values of the dependent variables after running a regression model

Tags: multiple-regression, adjustment

I have data coming from a satisfaction survey that was done in a big global company. In this survey, the managers of the different departments were rated by their employees (satisfaction from the managers).

It was suspected, that two variables will affect the satisfaction from the managers (apart from their personal performance):

- The first factor is the number of employees in the department: The smaller the department is, the more intimate it is, and therefore the manager is more “liked” by his employees.
- The second variable is a rate of how hard the work in the department is. It is assumed that the harder the work is, it will reflect in the satisfaction of the employees, who will see the manager responsible.

I ran a regression analysis using R (followed by scatter plots of satisfaction by both variables):

[image]

[image]

I have two main questions to ask you:

1. Both variables are statistically significant. However, the sample size was around 300 observations, which is fairly large. The coefficients are close to 0, and R square is only 6%. Can I actually say that these variables affect the satisfaction from the manager ?
2. Let's assume that both variables indeed affect the satisfaction, and that the coefficients are indeed correct. A manager get a grade, let's say for example 5. He/She may have got a higher grader if they worked in a different department, maybe a smaller one, or easier one. How can I **correct** the satisfaction score, using the regression coefficients ? I want to take my data (and future observations as well), and **adjust** the satisfaction score based on the number of employees and the difficulty of the department. I tried working with the regression formula, but not sure how to **correct / adjust** it properly. Any ideas ?

Thank you in advance, most appreciated !

Now I have the following question. Based on the regression results, if a manager got a certain rating, how can I adjust it, to take into account the size of the department and the rate of how hard the work is? Should I use the coefficients of the variables ? If so, how ?

For example: If a manager got a rating of 5, and he has 40 employees in his department, how can I estimate the rating he would get if he had only 20 employees ?

I am not looking for only a prediction based on the model, I wish to use the actual value of the dependent variable, the real value, and to adjust it to be more fair on the manager, now that I know how the two variables affect his rating, so the manager’s rating doesn’t get affected by the size of his department, and his evaluation is more fair.

Addition: Diagnostic plots as required.

[image]

Comment: What are those plots of? What units are your variables in? Have you checked your model diagnostics?

Comment: The y-axis is the satisfaction rating. The x-axis are the independent variables. The normality assumption doesn't hold, but the data is fairly large, so according to central limit theorem, it should be okay. Equal of variance assumption holds, more or less.

Comment: Data doesn't really look linear then... show us the output of `plot(model)`.

Comment: I have added the plots

Comment: Diagnostics look good, both your IV's are significant, however they may be practically insignificant, to be determined by you. As for the second question, I think you are asking for the interactions between the two IV's?

Comment: I will try to explain myself better. Assume that two managers are being evaluated. One is managing a group of 10 employees. The other is managing a group of 30 employees. The first one got a ranking of 6. The second one 5. The difference is due to how they manage, but according to the model, also to due to the size of the group. How can I calculate a more "fair" score for the second manager ? How can I adjust for the number of employees, now that I do know the change that every addition employee makes (the regression coefficient) ?

Comment: It appears the response might be the *mean* of *categorical* ratings (on a 1-7 scale) among each manager's employees.  Could you confirm that?  This detail is potentially important because it reveals something about how to evaluate the variability of the response, how to select a more appropriate regression analysis, and shed light on the apparent heteroscedasticity of the responses.  From these plots I would also guess that employee counts are inversely associated with difficulty: is that true?

Comment: Yes, you are very correct. The response came from a questionnaire. The employees rated the manager in a few likert scale questions (1-7). Then the mean was calculated for all questions. Then the mean of all employees was calculated. So yes, two means but initially a 1-7 scale. There is no evidence of an inverse relation between number of employees and difficulty.

Comment: I have taken the average value of both difficulty and number of employees, and I have used the coefficients of the regression to adjust the satisfaction, so all managers are values for same independent variables. I ran the regression again and got p-values of 1 and 0.99 for both variables. Does that make any sense ?